# Store the character of a string found in another string

Tags: python, string, string-concatenation

I have a string **str1 = "This is Kane and Kane is a coder"** and another string **str2 = "tsk"**
Now i want to remove all the characters of str2 which are appearing in str1 and store in another variable say word1

The result im expecting is

*str1 = "hi i ane and ane i a coder"*

*word1 = TssKKs*

```
word1 = ''
for i in str2:
    if i in str1.lower():
        word1 += i
        str1 = str1.lower().replace(i,'')
```

I guess this is not very optimised method as im running a loop for each character of str2 which will affect the time for long strings

Comment: Consider using `set(str2)` instead.

Comment: Note that because str2 is a string, `for i in str2:` iterates over the letters of the string.

Comment: If simple code is your goal, you could use `''.join([c for c in str1 if c.lower() not in str2])` to get all characters except those in `str2` (and simply remove the word `not` to get just the removed characters).

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, for every letter in `str2`, it needs to iterate over `str1` 2 times: in the line `if i in str1.lower()` and in `str1.replace(i,'')`. This means 6 times in in the example.

The following solution only iterates over `str1` once and the check against a `set` is fast. It builds 2 new strings in parallel in one pass.

```
str1 = "This is Kane and Kane is a coder"
str2 = "tsk"

word = ""
new_str = ""
remove = set(str2)
for letter in str1:
    if letter.lower() in remove:
        word += letter
    else:
        new_str += letter

print(word)
print(new_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

For short string like str2 the algorithm would not affect the performance and an optimisation would be exaggerating. Still, as it is short you can get rid of the inner loop and use an `if` statement instead. And you don't need to call lower in each loop. Just call it before entering the `for`:

```
word1 = ''
str1 = str1.lower()
for i in str1:
if i == "t" or i == "s" or i == "k":
    word1 += i
    str1 = str1.replace(i,'')
```

This should be way faster as the other letters are not tested against once one condition has evaluated to `true`.

And as @jarmod said, no need to convert a str to list, as str is iterable.

EDIT: for a case sensitive letters in word1, you need to use a temp variable:

```
word1 = ''
str1_low = str1.lower()
count = 0
for i in str1_low:
    count = count + 1
    if i == "t" or i == "s" or i == "k":
        word1 += str1[count]
        str1 = str1[:count] + str1[count+1:]
```

Comment: This code won't give me the expected value of word1

Comment: Also you can compute str1.lower() once and then use that variable, saves you computing that 3 times

Comment: @Talib It gives you the same value you'd get by executing your code. If you want to keep the letters' cases, then you need to lower the string of str1 after saving it in a temp variable, and getting the index of every letter you want to delete, then replacing that letter in the original string saved in str1.

Answer (score 0):

I mean in order to get the correct order and capitalization of word1 you probably need to loop over str1, so:

```
new_str1 = "" 
word1 = ""

for c in str1:
    if c in set(str2):
        word1 += c
    else:
        new_str1 +=c
```

And if capitalization don't matter.

well word1 = set(str2) and

```
import re

str1 = re.sub("[tsK]","", str1)
```